# how can I calculate the 4 corners of a finite plane that rests in a 3d space

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a finite plane in my application. The plane is described by its centre point C, its normal vector N and a scale vector S. S is not really a vector but rather a "convenient container" of scale values in order to "stretch" the plane in its 2 dimensions.

Think of S as the dimensionless distance between the pairs of corners in the X and Y dimensions (forget z-axis in the S vector). so if the corners of the plane are P1,P2,P3,P4 (starting from top left corner and numbering clockwise), then the vectors V12 (V12 = V2- V1) and V34 have the same distance. Likewise, the vectors V23 and V41 also have the same distance because the plane's shape is orthogonal.

So how can I use C,N and S to find the coordinates of the 4 corners?
I though I could start of with picking a random point, calculate the vector from C to this new point and, then calculate the `cross` product in order to get a vector on the plane. But this does not guarantee that the vector on the plane will be looking towards a specific point (towards a corner or a midpoint or something).

so how can I do it?

thank you in advnance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that data, you cannot determine the plane. (By "plane" you seem to mean "planar rectangle" rather than "infinite plane", right?)

Here's why.

Suppose the normal vector is $(0,0,1)$, and the center point is $(0,0,0)$, and the "side lengths" are both 2. You might think "Great -- it's just $-1 \le x,y \le 1$, the obvious square in the xy-plane.!"

But note that the square with corners $(\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, 0)$ also has the same center, same normal, and same side-lengths.

Thus your data is not sufficient to determine a single planar rectangle.

Comment: hi there! what other info could i use to alleviate this problem? I have 4 initial points, derived from a calibration phase. these points loosely resemble a parallelogram, but are not the exact corners of the plane. in fact, was generated based on these points. so could i use these 4 points to perhaps alleviate the problem of insufficient data?

Comment: Suppose I gave you a parallelogram in space...could you tell me the rectangle that this parallelogram SHOULD become? If you can't express what should happen in a single instance, it's asking a lot for me to give you a general solution, isn't it? :)